# how to remove all widgets in in user account dashboard?

Tags: magento-1.9, dashboard

It is required to totally clear the account dashboard page, to display custom layout which varies according to logged in customer's user group.
I did the following:

```
<customer_account_index translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="MyModule/Dashboard" name="block_Dashboard" template="customer/Dashboard.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

I can see the output of 'customer/Dashboard.phtml', but how to remove all of these widgets?

```
Account Information
Contact Information
...
```

Can't find any layout handlers, nor the template reference for them in app/core/Mage/Customer/*

Where to dig ? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not widget in a Magento meaning. Widgets are dynamic content block with admin settings, in your case it's only tab links.

You can find its in the layout file `customer.xml`

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
</block>
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
<remove name="tags_popular"/>
```

Look for the `addLink` calls in the layouts.

You can also remove the calls to this references in the template `customer/account/dashboard.phtml`